# PhpStorm/IntelliJ generate method from usage

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm looking for a generate method from usage. IntelliJ supports extract, rename etc. But if i write, for instance, $this->new_method($a) i would like to quickly generate this method in the same class. Does this exist or maybe there is a plugin for it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Place cursor on non existing method
2. <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (or wait and click on light bulb)
3. Choose `Add method` from submenu.

[image]

Comment: Yes i found out that i had removed "method" from inspections as it introduces a lot of warnings in the IDE. Thanks four your help.

Comment: Is it possible to tell PhpStorm signature of method? This intention creates private method with that name, it is possible to make protected method?

Comment: @JayGridley Unfortunately such option is not yet implemented for `@method` (but available when doing similar for `@property`) -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7192 (star/vote/comment to subscribe to get notified on progress). **P.S.** If you have "Shifter" plugin installed, you could use it to quickly iterate between private/public/protected -- faster that retyping it.

Comment: I am not able to get this Add method option in my phpstorm8 . Am i doing anything wrong ? Do i need to enable any setting ?

Comment: @maj So what menu do you get there on Alt+Enter? But in case if this option is available via separate intention, then please check if all options enabled in `Settings | Intentions | PHP`

Comment: Yes all the options are enabled in Intentions/PHP . I just tried to create class and tried the same, for that its working fine. But when i tried using inside drupal, it doesnt seems to show up.

Comment: @maj I'm not familiar with Drupal -- possibly it's Drupal specific issue (the way how it's coded or whatnot). Without having any sample project I would not be able to say where this a bug or actual code issue.

Comment: I get an error message `can not find target class for modification` even though i'm within my class. Suggestions?

Comment: @V-Light No ideas without screenshots and code to reproduce/to work with.